# Java long polling

Tags: java, android, node.js, long-polling

I wrote a server with node.js but it gives the data when only receiver GET requests. 
I am writing a Java application to work with it. But what to use, how to do. Can you provide examples or something like I should use?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what the question is. What are you trying to do? Why the `long-polling` tag? - please explain.

Comment: If you are trying to figure out how to do get requests on Android, search for it on SO ('[android] get request'), there's lots of info to find on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Socket.IO client for java - https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client